# How to set website-global hourCycle option

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date-format, date-formatting

In many places in our project date formatting is being used. Dates is being formatted in 3-rd party libraries (such as SyncFusion EJ2 for example), and it's impossible unfortunately to define explicit format everywhere.

In Firefox hours is displayed in 0-23 format (which is fully correct). However, Chrome use 1-24 format for hour displaying.

Is there are any possibility to set `hourCycle` variable in `Intl.DateTimeFormat` globally which should affect all the page locale parameters?

Thank you very much